# Checking if the string is in proper format in Shell Scripting

Tags: shell

I am trying to check if the string is in format in shell script.
below is the code i am trying and the output i want to get.

Format: `<datatype>(length,length) | <datatype>(length,length)`

I have multiple cases with this scenario, if both datatypes have `()` then it should show pass, else fail.

Eg. `decimal(1,0)|number(11,0)` this should pass but `int|number(11,0)` or `decimal(1,0)|int` should fail.

Code1:

```
INPUT='decimal(1,0)|number(11,0)'
sub="[A-Z][a-z]['!@#$ %^&*()_+'][0-9][|][A-Z][a-z]['!@#$ %^&*()_+'][0-9][|]"
if [ "$INPUT" == "$sub" ]; then
    echo "Passed"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Code 2:

```
INPUT='decimal(1,0)|number(11,0)'
sub="decimal"
if [ "$INPUT" == *"("*") |"*"("*") " ]; then
    echo "Passed"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```

Any help will be fine. Also note, I am very new to shell scripting.

Comment: You want `=~`, not `==`, for a regular expression operation. `=` is a glob. And if you _do_ want a glob, you can't quote the right-hand side -- it should be `[[ $INPUT = $sub ]]` -- note `[[` instead of `[`; `[` only supports exact comparisons (and only in `[[` are unquoted expansions safe).

Comment: The above is only true in shells like bash with ksh extensions; `/bin/sh` doesn't support `[[` at all, nor does it have any kind of built-in regex support, though you _can_ evaluate globs there using `case`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and information . But i require the sub string which i can use in the if condition and add the other code i wan to impelement.

Comment: You can nest `case` inside of `if`. Baseline POSIX-standard `/bin/sh` simply doesn't support any substring operation without `case`; you need an extended shell (ksh, bash, zsh, etc) for that to be built-in.

Comment: `if case $string in $pattern) true;; *) false;; esac; then ...`

Comment: Also, note that `[` isn't guaranteed to support `==` at all. The **only** [standard-defined](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) string comparison operator is `=`.

Comment: @nishitdey what's the meaning of `'!@#$ %^&*()_+'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading both values into variables, first removing alpha characters and then checking variables are not empty

```
result='FAIL'
input='int|number(6,10)'

IFS="|" read val1 val2 <<<"$(tr -d '[:alpha:]' <<<"$input")"

if [ -n "$val1" ] && [ -n "$val2" ]; then
    result='PASS'
fi
echo "$result: val1='$val1' val2='$val2'"
```

Result:

```
FAIL: val1='' val2='(6,10)'
```

For `input='decimal(8,9)|number(6,10)'`

```
PASS: val1='(8,9)' val2='(6,10)'
```

Answer (score 2):

That looks like just a simple regex to write.

```
INPUT='decimal(1,0)|number(11,0)'
if printf "%s" "$INPUT" | grep -qEx '[a-z]+\([0-9]+,[0-9]+\)(\|[a-z]+\([0-9]+,[0-9]+\))*'; then
    echo "Passed"
else
    echo "No"
fi
```